# How to start debugging "The http server closed the connection unexpectedly before delivering responses for 1 outstanding requests"

Tags: scala, akka, amazon-sqs, akka-http

I have turned on DEBUG level logging for my application but am not able to see anything useful for why the http server would close the connection. This exception happens within alpakka's SqsPublishSink which uses `SqsAsyncClient`. It doesn't appear to be an issue with SQS specifically but the akka http client used to send the SQS messages. These issues started appearing out of the blue so I'm not sure where to start with looking into this one.

```
[DEBUG] [06/19/2020 17:18:04.081] [aws-akka-http-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-38] [aws-akka-http/Pool(shared->https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:443)] Dispatching request [POST  Default(6331 bytes)] to pool
[DEBUG] [06/19/2020 17:18:04.081] [aws-akka-http-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-38] [aws-akka-http/Pool(shared->https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:443)] [0 (Idle)] Dispatching request [POST / Default(6331 bytes)]
[DEBUG] [06/19/2020 17:18:04.081] [aws-akka-http-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-38] [aws-akka-http/Pool(shared->https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:443)] [0 (Idle)] Before event [onNewRequest] In state [Idle] for [951 ms]
[DEBUG] [06/19/2020 17:18:04.081] [aws-akka-http-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-38] [aws-akka-http/Pool(shared->https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:443)] [0 (PushingRequestToConnection)] After event [onNewRequest] State change [Idle] -> [PushingRequestToConnection]
[DEBUG] [06/19/2020 17:18:04.081] [aws-akka-http-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-38] [aws-akka-http/Pool(shared->https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:443)] [0 (PushingRequestToConnection)] Before event [onRequestDispatched] In state [PushingRequestToConnection] for [0 ms]
[DEBUG] [06/19/2020 17:18:04.081] [aws-akka-http-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-38] [aws-akka-http/Pool(shared->https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:443)] [0 (WaitingForResponse)] After event [onRequestDispatched] State change [PushingRequestToConnection] -> [WaitingForResponse]
[DEBUG] [06/19/2020 17:18:04.081] [aws-akka-http-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-38] [aws-akka-http/Pool(shared->https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:443)] [0 (WaitingForResponse)] Before event [onRequestEntityCompleted] In state [WaitingForResponse] for [0 ms]
[DEBUG] [06/19/2020 17:18:04.081] [aws-akka-http-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-38] [aws-akka-http/Pool(shared->https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:443)] [0 (WaitingForResponse)] After event [onRequestEntityCompleted] State change [WaitingForResponse] -> [WaitingForResponse]
[DEBUG] [06/19/2020 17:18:04.145] [aws-akka-http-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-19] [aws-akka-http/Pool(shared->https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:443)] [0 (WaitingForResponse)] Connection cancelled
[DEBUG] [06/19/2020 17:18:04.146] [aws-akka-http-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-19] [aws-akka-http/Pool(shared->https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:443)] [0 (WaitingForResponse)] Connection failed
[DEBUG] [06/19/2020 17:18:04.146] [aws-akka-http-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-19] [aws-akka-http/Pool(shared->https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:443)] [0 (WaitingForResponse)] Before event [onConnectionFailed] In state [WaitingForResponse] for [65 ms]
[DEBUG] [06/19/2020 17:18:04.146] [aws-akka-http-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-19] [aws-akka-http/Pool(shared->https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:443)] [0 (WaitingForResponse)] Ongoing request [POST / Default(6331 bytes)] is failed because of [connection failure]: [The http server closed the connection unexpectedly before delivering responses for 1 outstanding requests]
[DEBUG] [06/19/2020 17:18:04.146] [aws-akka-http-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-19] [aws-akka-http/Pool(shared->https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:443)] [0 (WaitingForResponseDispatch)] After event [onConnectionFailed] State change [WaitingForResponse] -> [WaitingForResponseDispatch]
[DEBUG] [06/19/2020 17:18:04.146] [aws-akka-http-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-19] [aws-akka-http/Pool(shared->https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:443)] [0 (WaitingForResponseDispatch)] Before event [onResponseDispatchable] In state [WaitingForResponseDispatch] for [0 ms]
[DEBUG] [06/19/2020 17:18:04.147] [aws-akka-http-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-19] [aws-akka-http/Pool(shared->https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:443)] [0 (Failed)] After event [onResponseDispatchable] State change [WaitingForResponseDispatch] -> [Failed]
[DEBUG] [06/19/2020 17:18:04.147] [aws-akka-http-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-19] [aws-akka-http/Pool(shared->https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:443)] [0 (Failed)] State change from [WaitingForResponseDispatch] to [Failed(akka.http.impl.engine.client.OutgoingConnectionBlueprint$UnexpectedConnectionClosureException: The http server closed the connection unexpectedly before delivering responses for 1 outstanding requests)]. Closing the existing connection.
[DEBUG] [06/19/2020 17:18:04.147] [aws-akka-http-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-19] [aws-akka-http/Pool(shared->https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:443)] [0 (Unconnected)] Slot became idle... Trying to pull
{"@timestamp":"2020-06-19T17:18:04.166-04:00","@version":"1","message":"error occurred in event stream","logger_name":"myorg.events.integration.Foo$","thread_name":"poker-actor-system-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-47","level":"ERROR","level_value":40000,"stack_trace":"java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: software.amazon.awssdk.core.exception.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: The http server closed the connection unexpectedly before delivering responses for 1 outstanding requests
\tat software.amazon.awssdk.utils.CompletableFutureUtils.errorAsCompletionException(CompletableFutureUtils.java:60)
\tat software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.AsyncExecutionFailureExceptionReportingStage.lambda$execute$0(AsyncExecutionFailureExceptionReportingStage.java:51)
\tat java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniHandle(CompletableFuture.java:822)
\tat java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniHandle.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:797)
\tat java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:474)
\tat java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeExceptionally(CompletableFuture.java:1977)
\tat software.amazon.awssdk.utils.CompletableFutureUtils.lambda$forwardExceptionTo$0(CompletableFutureUtils.java:74)
\tat java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:760)
\tat java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:736)
\tat java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:474)
\tat java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeExceptionally(CompletableFuture.java:1977)
\tat software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.AsyncRetryableStage$RetryingExecutor.maybeAttemptExecute(AsyncRetryableStage.java:85)
\tat software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.AsyncRetryableStage$RetryingExecutor.maybeRetryExecute(AsyncRetryableStage.java:144)
\tat software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.AsyncRetryableStage$RetryingExecutor.lambda$attemptExecute$1(AsyncRetryableStage.java:125)
\tat java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:760)
\tat java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:736)
\tat java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:474)
\tat java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeExceptionally(CompletableFuture.java:1977)
\tat software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.MakeAsyncHttpRequestStage$WrappedErrorForwardingResponseHandler.onError(MakeAsyncHttpRequestStage.java:122)
\tat com.github.matsluni.akkahttpspi.RequestRunner.$anonfun$run$6(RequestRunner.scala:66)
\tat com.github.matsluni.akkahttpspi.RequestRunner.$anonfun$run$6$adapted(RequestRunner.scala:66)
\tat scala.util.Success.foreach(Try.scala:253)
\tat scala.concurrent.Future.$anonfun$foreach$1$adapted(Future.scala:229)
\tat scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:64)
\tat akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$AbstractBatch.processBatch(BatchingExecutor.scala:55)
\tat akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch.$anonfun$run$1(BatchingExecutor.scala:92)
\tat scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
\tat scala.concurrent.BlockContext$.withBlockContext(BlockContext.scala:85)
\tat akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch.run(BatchingExecutor.scala:92)
\tat akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:41)
\tat akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator.scala:49)
\tat akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
\tat akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
\tat akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
\tat akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
Caused by: software.amazon.awssdk.core.exception.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: The http server closed the connection unexpectedly before delivering responses for 1 outstanding requests
\tat software.amazon.awssdk.core.exception.SdkClientException$BuilderImpl.build(SdkClientException.java:98)
\tat software.amazon.awssdk.core.exception.SdkClientException.create(SdkClientException.java:43)
\tat software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.utils.RetryableStageHelper.setLastException(RetryableStageHelper.java:201)
\tat software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.AsyncRetryableStage$RetryingExecutor.maybeRetryExecute(AsyncRetryableStage.java:143)
\t... 22 common frames omitted
Caused by: akka.http.impl.engine.client.OutgoingConnectionBlueprint$UnexpectedConnectionClosureException: The http server closed the connection unexpectedly before delivering responses for 1 outstanding requests
\tat akka.http.impl.engine.client.OutgoingConnectionBlueprint$.$anonfun$apply$6(OutgoingConnectionBlueprint.scala:123)
\tat akka.http.impl.engine.client.OutgoingConnectionBlueprint$.$anonfun$apply$6$adapted(OutgoingConnectionBlueprint.scala:123)
\tat akka.http.impl.util.One2OneBidiFlow$One2OneBidi$$anon$1$$anon$4.onUpstreamFinish(One2OneBidiFlow.scala:97)
\tat akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreter.processEvent(GraphInterpreter.scala:506)
\tat akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreter.execute(GraphInterpreter.scala:376)
\tat akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreterShell.runBatch(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:606)
\tat akka.stream.impl.fusing.ActorGraphInterpreter$SimpleBoundaryEvent.execute(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:47)
\tat akka.stream.impl.fusing.ActorGraphInterpreter$SimpleBoundaryEvent.execute$(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:43)
\tat akka.stream.impl.fusing.ActorGraphInterpreter$BatchingActorInputBoundary$OnComplete.execute(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:76)
\tat akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreterShell.processEvent(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:581)
\tat akka.stream.impl.fusing.ActorGraphInterpreter.akka$stream$impl$fusing$ActorGraphInterpreter$$processEvent(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:749)
\tat akka.stream.impl.fusing.ActorGraphInterpreter$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:764)
\tat akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:539)
\tat akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive$(Actor.scala:537)
\tat akka.stream.impl.fusing.ActorGraphInterpreter.aroundReceive(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:671)
\tat akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:614)
\tat akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:583)
\tat akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:268)
\tat akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:229)
\tat akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:241)
\t... 4 common frames omitted
"}
```

Comment: If you post the source code in github I'll try to help